# Status of new Cron is missing in cron_schedule

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, cron, crontab

I am developing a custom module and in that I am using Cron to disable the status of notifications.

I have written this code in `config.xml`

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <disable_notifications>
            <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>notifications/cronjobs::disableNotifications</model></run>
        </disable_notifications>
        <test>
            <schedule><cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>notifications/cronjobs::test</model></run>
        </test>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

All other crons expect this two are working fine and getting executed as scheduled but my crons are getting scheduled in database table 'cron_schedule' but the status updates in **missed**.
[image]

Please let me know the solution. I am stuck with this problem from 3 days.

Comment: Can you provide the Exception caught pls?

Comment: I am getting this message everytime when it is missed.

exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Too late for the schedule.'

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, cron jobs are marked as missed based on the configuration under **System > Configuration > Cron > Missed if not run within** field.

I had the problem once where the cron was running once per hour, and that value was set to 15 minutes and thus a lot of jobs were marked as missed.

I suggest you ensure your cron runs every 5 minutes as suggested by the Magento documentation and if you can't do that, maybe update that configuration according to your configuration.

### Update

According to your database table, it seems like those cronjobs generate an exception as you can see from the exception column: `exception Mage_Core_Exception with message Too...` . I'm pretty sure that's the root cause of your problem. Open one of those rows and find the full exception. Fixing the exception would most likely fix your problem.

Comment: I have configured cron to run after every 5 minutes and I have also configured System > Configuration > Cron > Missed if not run within field. But both of them together didn't worked for me. Can you suggest any other option?

Comment: @GauravAgrawal yes see my updated answer

Comment: It shows exception: exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Too late for the schedule.' in /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:595.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal well yeah that's the error that matches the description I gave you first. You definitely have a problem with your cron. Double check how your cron is configured on your server

Comment: All the default cronjobs in magento like: **newsletter_send_all**, **core_email_queue_send_all** are executed successfully in that table.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal yes your screenshot clairly says the opposite as I can see two `newsletter_send_all` marked as missed. Plus it's because some of them run properly that your cron is properly configured. If the ones that run properly are configured to run every 15min and your cron runs every 10min then that's ok. But if you add cron jobs that are configured to run every 1 and every 5 minutes then you'll start getting some misses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48717/discussion-between-gaurav-agrawal-and-raphael-at-digital-pianism).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your config for `system/cron/schedule_lifetime` is at least as small as your "fastest" cron.

In `app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer` you can find the relevant code:

```
$scheduleLifetime = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SCHEDULE_LIFETIME) * 60;
$now = time();
[...]
$time = strtotime($schedule->getScheduledAt());
[...]
if ($time < $now - $scheduleLifetime) {
    $errorStatus = Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::STATUS_MISSED;
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('cron')->__('Too late for the schedule.'));
}
```

I'd also make sure your crontab executes `cron.php` (or `cron.sh`) in Magento's root folder, at least every minute since your `notifications/cronjobs::test` cron is supposed to run every minute.

Comment: What do you mean about this: Make sure your config for system/cron/schedule_lifetime is at least as small as your "fastest" cron.